# Pick a number that is better than your friends

Tags: puzzle, game-theory

Consider the following game.

There are $n$ players, each one has to pick a (real) number $x$ between $0$ and $100$.  There is one round to the game.  The winner is the person whose number is closest to $10\sqrt{\mu}$ where $\mu$ is the mean of the choices made by all the other players.

How would one formulate the problem of choosing optimal play mathematically and is there an optimal strategy?

Comment: What happens if two people name the same number?

Comment: @Abstraction Then it's a draw between them.

Comment: What is a draw in terms of optimization (i.e. what is better - a draw with probability $p_1$ or winning with probability $p_2$)?

Comment: @Abstraction Let me change the rules slightly to make this simpler. If there is a draw the winner is chosen randomly from amongst those people who are drawing.

Comment: Intuitively, the optimal solution is to pick $10\sqrt{50}$ since the expected number of mean is $50$. However to justify the expected mean is $50$ would involve integral over some probability function but that does not seem easy. Maybe there is some easy way to justify the intuition.

Comment: @cr001: The point is, if $10\sqrt {50}$ were the optimal solution, then everybody would choose it, and it wouldn't be the optimal solution any more $-$ the optimal solution would be $10\sqrt{10\sqrt{50}}$. And so on. (This sequence converges to $100$, as Matthew Gunn's answer shows.)

Comment: The main idea is you should: (1) formulate beliefs about your friends and (2) play a best response. If you think they're all boneheads who will choose 50, then you should choose 10*sqrt(50). If you think they're all super smart, and they know you're smart, you know they know etc...., then everyone might reason that everyone will choose 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic game theory problem.

You want to formulate each player's best response function, that is, describe each player's optimal action as a function of other player's actions.

In this case, that is remarkably simple.
Player $i$'s optimal pick as a function of other player's picks would solve the equation:
$$ x_i = 10\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j} x_j} $$

A Nash equilibrium is a tuple $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ where everyone is playing their best response. Taking a shortcut, let's look for symmetric equilibria: then $\mu = x$. Solving for the fixed point.

$$ x = 10 \sqrt{x}$$
Hence symmetric Nash Equilibria: $$x = 100  \quad \quad \quad \quad x = 0$$

If we all pick $100$, everyone splits the win and no one can do better by deviating. If we all pick $0$, everyone splits the win and no one can do better by deviating. Either outcome is what we might expect if everyone were perfectly rational. If you have alternative beliefs, you should play your best response function given those beliefs.

Small note: you need to assume $n > 2$ or it doesn't matter at all what anybody picks since both players would always be equidistant from the mean.

Comment: If everyone picks $100$ then you win with probability $1/n$.

Comment: @Lembik You still have no incentive to deviate. If you pick anything else, you straight up lose if everyone else picks 100. You can split the prize by picking 100 or choose anything else and get 0. (assuming n > 2)

Comment: Thank you. It's an interesting definition of optimality. It's certainly the case that if everyone else choose 100 you want to choose 100. But if everyone else choose anything less than 81, it's bad idea to choose 100.

Comment: You want to play your best response based on your beliefs. If I belief everyone else is going to play 50, I should play 10 * sqrt(50).  But if we all know that everyone is rational, we all know that we know everyone is rational etc..., then we should all play 100 or 0.

Comment: It seems that if everyone picks a random number in the range they have a  $1/n$ chance of winning which is at least as good as the Nash Equilibrium solution. Why is this not optimal?

Comment: @lembik that is not right. If you had an infinite number of people choosing a random number between 0 and 100, the average would be 50 and I would almost certainly win by picking 10 * sqrt(50). If everyone randomized like that, then me randomizing as well isn't a best response.

Comment: Ah..good point.

Comment: A problem in many game theory situations is too many Nash equilibria, some of which have problems. There are all sorts of refined notions of equilibrium: trembling hand, subgame perfect, bayesian etc...  In this instance, the everyone playing 100 equlibrium seems more stable to me than the everyone play 0. Everyone plays 0 is a bit more knife edge balance.